# Google Maps Platform Payment

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting [OR-CBAT-11] error while doing payment for Google maps platform. What does it mean? How to iron out this?

I tried entering all details required and uploaded the corresponding documents. But my verification was getting failed. There is no format for uploading documents for verification. I uploaded it in JPEG format.

Comment: Contact your bank or card issuer and ask them. Use a different card. Some cards from countries like India are not supported. ***Due to issues with the 3D Secure verification service, we can't accept Indian debit cards for automatic payments at this time. We also can't accept certain Indian credit cards. If your card is being rejected, try another credit card.*** This link has more information at the bottom: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency